# Looping over dirs using `find . -depth 1 -type d`

Tags: bash, find

I've been given a script to run, but it produces an error when calling `find . -depth 1 -type d`.
It produces the following error,

```
find: paths must precede expression: `1'
```

This is the line in which it fails,

```
for dir in `find . -depth 1 -type d`
do
    ....
```

I have tried quite a few things without success. And I don't really see why it gives the error since it seems to me at least, that the paths does indeed precede the "1".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all `find` implementations support `-depth 1`. A portable alternative would be:

```
find . ! -name . -type d -prune
```